# Winning in roulette when betting on one number infinitely

Tags: probability

Suppose you join a game of roulette. You choose to only bet on one number all night until you win once, then you stop. Say the probability of winning is 1/37, how will the probability distribution look and also what is the mathematics behind it?

UPDATE:  I am asking for the probability distribution for the number of times played.

Comment: Probability distribution of what?

Comment: The probability of what? Are you asking about your expected loss? Or the probability of any given loss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the number of bets, then:

$$P(X=n)=\frac{36^{n-1}}{37^n}$$

---

**ELABORATION:**

The probability of $n$ bets is equivalent to the probability of $n-1$ bad bets and $1$ good bet.

The probability of $n-1$ bad bets is $\left(\frac{36}{37}\right)^{n-1}$, and the probability of $1$ good bet is $\left(\frac{1}{37}\right)^1$.

So the probability of $n$ bets is:

$$\left(\frac{36}{37}\right)^{n-1}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{37}\right)^1=\frac{36^{n-1}}{37^n}$$

Comment: Reading your update, it appears that my bet (guess) was correct.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your how you were thinking to get the above equation?

Comment: @C.T.: See updated answer.

Comment: @C.T.: You're welcome :)